# Dropdown list with repeated value fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've bound the database to dropdownlist using this simple code:

```
 DropDownList ddlWorkArea = new DropDownList();
    ddlWorkArea.ID = "ddlWorkArea" + rownum.ToString();
    ddlWorkArea.DataSource = WorkArea;
    ddlWorkArea.DataTextField = "WorkArea";
    ddlWorkArea.DataValueField = "WorkCode";
    ddlWorkArea.AutoPostBack = true;
    ddlWorkArea.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlWorkArea_SelectedIndexChanged);
    ddlWorkArea.DataBind();
```

The data table behind is quite simple and looks similar to

```
WorkArea                WorkCode
--------------------------------
Please Select 
Cargo Logistic          36170
Ops                     24100
Depot                   23170
Shipside                24100
```

As you can see, the "Shipside" and "Ops" have the same WorkCode. What I've notices, that after the SelectedIndexChanged event the display text of dropdownlist changes from "Shipside" to "Ops" - as I understand because for the server those two fields are identical... unfortunately it is not so for the user (in my Web Page I need to store both the WorkArea and WorkCode)

I know I could use the WorkAre as both data and text field and then query the database to get the WorkCode, but that sounds awfully complicated for such simple matter, I could change the duplicated code to something like `24100x` and later trim the `x`, but that seems very inelegant...

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: concat the WorkArea and WorkCode, "24100Ops" & "24100Shipside"

Comment: Yes, it is similar to my own proposed solution - does it mean that there is no normal way of using dropown lists with repeated values?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no normal ways.

Comment: never use same code for 2 different things. It's always a bad idea and might haunt you later on if not now.